# Impala Shell - Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain on Cloudera cluster

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudera, aws-cli, impala

I have a Cloudera cluster with 3 worker nodes, 1 manager and 1 gateway machine. I have configured aws credentials on the cluster with the secret key and access key. But I'm unable to perform any action on the s3 bucket from my Gateway machine. Creating tables or database or querying throws the exception :

ERROR: AnalysisException: null
CAUSED BY: AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

I'm able to list the buckets or perform actions related to aws CLI. Only in Impala shell, it throws this error.

Comment: These are on the same machine, correct? How did you configure your credentials?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by same machine. I'm accessing Impala from client machine (Gateway) - on a 5 node Cloudera cluster. I added the access key and secret key on the HDFS Client Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hdfs-site.xml field. Also added the same properties on hive-site and impala configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Each impalad node on the cluster is actually doing the work, so each node needs to have access to S3, not just the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an AWS AccessKey in hdfs-site.xml.
You can follow the procedure on this Cloudera article : 
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/impala_s3.html

You need to add the following properties in your hdfs-site/xml  :

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
  <value>your_access_key</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
  <value>your_secret_key</value>
</property>
```

If using a proxy, you also need to add fs.s3a.proxy.host and fs.s3a.proxy.port properties.